# SML - Multiplying Coefficients of Polynomials

Tags: list, sml

I have two lists that contain coefficients for two different polynomials, and I'm looking to write a function that can multiply them together (i.e F-O-I-L).

The function I wrote is not complete, however I was just using it to test my understanding of how it should work.

```
fun polyMult(nil, nil) = nil
  | polyMult(M as x::xs, N as y::ys) = 
        (x * y)::polyMult(xs, ys);
```

Am I on the right track?

Also, I have an error message stating `uncaught exception Match [nonexhaustive match failure]`

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are not on the right track. Your function just zips the two lists with multiplication, which is not how F-O-I-L works. By definition of polynomial multiplication, your function should return a polynomial of a higher degree. [This](http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/polynomials/functions/mult_functions.html) should be helpful for you to understand F-O-I-L.

The nonexhaustive match error means that you are not covering all the possible cases for the two lists in your pattern matching. In fact, you are missing the two cases where one of the lists is `nil` and the other one is not. In terms of your function this would mean the cases where the function has the lists of coefficients from polynomials of different degrees.

If you want to separately handle those two cases you are currently missing, you can go like this:

```
fun polyMult(M, N) = case (M,N) of
    ([], [])       => []
  | ([], y::ys)    => ...
  | (x::xs, [])    => ...
  | (x::xs, y::ys) => ...
```

Of course, replace the dots with your implementation. I hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: I tried modifying my function, which should take `hd(M)` and multiply it by the `hd(N)` for every recursive call of `polyMult` => `fun polyMult(M,N) = (hd(M) * hd(N))::polyMult(M, tl(N));`       however, I just get the concatenation of N @ M.

Comment: @mynorka That definition doesn't have a base case, so it doesn't work. Since you do pattern matching, you can use `x::xs` and `y::ys` as you do in the question, you don't need to use `hd` and `tl`.

Comment: I'm still given an output of just the two lists concatenated. Is there a specific function for `lists` to multiply two elements together?

Comment: If you're looking for a function where `m([1,2,3],[4,5,6])` is `[4,10,18]`, you can easily define one: `fun m(l1,l2) = map op* (ListPair.zip(l1,l2));` Your function in the question does the same thing, except that it only works on the lists with the same length, if you want such a function, I suggest adding the necessary extra cases to that one. (This might not be useful for F-O-I-L, but anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

```
fun foldL F y nil = y
    | foldL F y (x::xr) = foldL F (F(x,y)) xr;

fun polymult(M:real list, nil) = nil
    | polymult(nil, N) = nil
    | polymult(m::mr, N) = foldL(fn(x,a) => x * a) m N::polymult(mr,N);
```

thatll do what you want it to.